# How can I pass an InnerException using throw statement outside catch block?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a `ParsingException` class which takes 2 inputs in a constructor.
1. A string message
2. Exception InnerException

```
public ParsingException(string errorMessage, Exception innerException) : base(errorMessage, innerException)
{

}
```

If I use it in the following way,

```
if (some condition)
{
    throw new ParsingException("NoIdNumber:Length of Id Number is 0",**NEED TO PASS AN INNER EXCEPTION OVER HERE**);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you don't have an exception to pass, then why not add a constructor to `ParsingException` that just takes a string?

Comment: Have you tried passing `null`? Or maybe `new Exception("Fun message")`?

Comment: Just pass null there, no need to create fake inner exceptions if you don't have real one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create the inner exception as well (if you aren't catching it, you can't pass something you don't have so you either catch it or create it) eg.

```
if (parsedValue == null)
{
    throw new ParsingException("Parsing failed", new NullReferenceException("Value was null"));
}
else if (parsedValue.Id.Length == 0)
{
    // Assuming you have a custom "NoIdException" exception defined, you can just create a new instance of it and pass that. Otherwise you can create a generic "Exception"
    var noIdException = new NoIdException("No Id was provided"); // Don't throw, just create so we can pass to the ParsingException
    throw new ParsingException("NoIdNumber:Length of Id Number is 0", noIdException);
}
```

EDIT: In response to the comment from @Evk, although I have answered the question that was asked I do agree that creating "fake" exceptions isn't necessarily best practice. I assume this was a follow up to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936992/why-innerexception-is-null-while-catching-the-exception-from-a-parent-exception) about accessing a custom `IdNumberNONEParsingException` as the `InnerException` of the thrown `ParsingException`.

I just wanted to point out that there may be better ways to handle this without needing to mess with the `InnerExcepion`, for example you can have multiple catch clauses to handle either exception separately eg.

```
try { ... }
catch(IdNumberNONEParsingException e) { ... }
catch(ParsingException e) { ... }
finally { ... }
```

Or because `IdNumberNONEParsingException` inherits from `ParsingException`, catching a `ParsingException` will catch both eg.

```
try { ... }
catch(ParsingException e) // Will still catch IdNumberNONEParsingException
{
    if (e is IdNumberNONEParsingException) // Checks if the exception that was thrown was an IdNumberNONEParsingException
    {
        // Special logic for handling IdNumberNONEParsingException
    }
    else
    {
        // Special logic for handling non-IdNumberNONEParsingExceptions
    }
    // Shared logic for handling all types of ParsingExceptions eg. logging, cleanup, etc.
}
```

Comment: But still your answer is misleading. "You would need to create the inner exception as well" - why? Just pass null.

Comment: @Evk Because the question is "How can I pass an InnnerException" not "How can I throw this exception without an InnerException"